# opening Drawer on bloc pattern

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bloc

after some days to resolve this problem, i can't

i implemented simple blok pattern on my app and i want to open `Drawer` by pressing on `FloatingActionButton` or on `Icons.menu` icon, but my code as

```
Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
```

don't work

my code:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: BlocBuilder<HomeEvent, HomeState>(
      bloc: _homeBloc,
      builder: (BuildContext context, HomeState state) {
        Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); //<---- don't work
        if (state is HandleDrawerMenuClick) {
          _onWidgetDidBuild(() {
            Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); //<---- don't work
            _showToast(context); //<---- work fine
          });
        }
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () {
            customPop(context);
          },
          child: Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: Scaffold(
              primary: true,
              appBar: ApplicationToolbar(homeBloc: _homeBloc),
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); //<---- don't work
                  _showToast(context); //<---- work fine
                },
              ),
              floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
              bottomNavigationBar: AppBottomNavigationBar(),
              drawer: AppDrawer(),
              body: _fragments[_currentIndex],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
);
```

`HomeEvent` class:

```
class HomeEvent extends Equatable{
  HomeEvent([List props = const []]) : super(props);
}

class OnDrawerMenuClicked extends HomeEvent {

  @override
  String toString() => 'OnDrawerMenuClicked clicked';
}

class OnDrawerMenuItemsClicked extends HomeEvent {
  var onItem = 1;

  OnDrawerMenuItemsClicked({this.onItem});

  @override
  String toString() => 'OnDrawerMenuItemsClicked clicked';
}
```

`HomeState` class:

```
class HomeState extends Equatable{
  HomeState([List props = const[]]):super(props);
}

class HomeInitial extends HomeState{
  @override
  String toString()=>'HomeInitial';
}
class HandleDrawerMenuClick extends HomeState{
  @override
  String toString()=>'HandleDrawerMenuClick';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening your drawer with BLoC pattern is overly complicated. You need to wrap your `FloatingActionButton` with a builder widget that will provide the right context for opening the drawer for you and it opens up without the need of using Bloc pattern.

**Smaple code for opening drawer with FAB**

```
 return Scaffold(
      appBar:  AppBar(title: Text('Drawer FAB'),),
      drawer: Drawer(child: Text('drawer content'),),
      floatingActionButton: Builder( builder:(context) => 
                          FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), 
                              onPressed: (){ 
                                  Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                              },
                          )),
);
```

Comment: if i have appbar in other class how can open drawer? for example in separated appBar my `automaticallyImplyLeading` is `false` and i want to use custom icon and clicking on cause of opening drawer

Comment: I don't really get the question. You can still open the drawer by clicking the button even if `automaticallyImplyLeading` is false

Comment: yes sure i can click on that, but when i set `automaticallyImplyLeading`  to false drawer couldn't open because `automaticallyImplyLeading` cause of that if thats `true`

Comment: That is strange. It opens in mine even when it is set to false.

Comment: please let me to check again

Comment: try restarting.